# Divide image into segments to change them with css on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have an image like this, divided into 4 segments. I want to be able to change the blur of each segment on hover. For example:

```
#segment1:hover {
  filter: blur(50px);
}
```

[image]

I tried turning those segments into svg masks and then using clip path like in this example [this example](https://sarasoueidan.com/demos/css-svg-clipping/html-img-clipped-with-css-svg-clippath/index.html), but css still interprets it like a whole image even though only a part of it is visible.
The shape of the curves dividing those segments is complex and (I suppose) svg should be used, so javascript tricks for checking x and y position don't work, as well as html < map > tag.

How would you solve such problem? Thank you!

Here's the svg code for the first segment mask (just in case).

```
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="1920.000000pt" height="1081.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 1920.000000 1081.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<path transform="translate(0.000000,1081.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none" d="M0 6557 l0 -4254 118 -12 c64 -7 137 -18 162 -23 73 -17 432 -19 530
-3 47 8 124 18 171 24 109 12 305 56 389 86 36 13 88 32 115 41 178 62 184 64
500 247 204 118 404 270 593 451 204 195 424 506 538 758 20 45 46 97 56 113
10 17 18 38 18 48 0 10 12 41 26 69 15 29 35 83 46 121 10 38 27 86 38 107 10
20 24 59 31 86 7 27 24 76 39 109 30 65 68 168 96 255 53 169 121 283 298 499
158 193 340 327 536 393 l95 33 220 -1 220 0 136 -36 c75 -20 179 -55 231 -77
52 -22 153 -57 224 -76 71 -20 143 -40 159 -46 68 -24 166 -48 241 -58 43 -5
121 -16 171 -23 115 -15 205 -4 378 47 180 53 220 70 314 135 312 214 446 443
523 890 15 89 4 313 -28 595 -34 301 -43 630 -21 771 15 89 90 341 131 436 18
41 95 177 159 278 64 100 141 195 251 308 233 239 386 339 746 487 307 126
430 214 538 382 41 63 51 115 52 247 0 84 -6 132 -26 215 -15 58 -27 116 -29
128 -6 61 -160 292 -289 435 l-61 68 -4317 0 -4318 0 0 -4253z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: could you provide a working (or not properly working) example we can start from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps:

```css
.x { opacity:0; }
.x:hover { opacity:1; }
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="300" viewBox="0 0 800 600">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur">
       <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="8"/>
    </filter>
    <image href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkIzu.jpg"
           width="800" height="600" id="img"/>
    <clipPath id="c1">
      <path d="M0 0h400v300h-400z"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="c2">
      <path d="M400 0h400v300h-400z"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="c3">
      <path d="M0 300h400v300h-400z"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="c4">
      <path d="M400 300h400v300h-400z"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#img"/>
  <use xlink:href="#img" filter="url(#blur)"
       clip-path="url(#c1)" class="x"/>
  <use xlink:href="#img" filter="url(#blur)"
       clip-path="url(#c2)" class="x"/>
  <use xlink:href="#img" filter="url(#blur)"
       clip-path="url(#c3)" class="x"/>
  <use xlink:href="#img" filter="url(#blur)"
       clip-path="url(#c4)" class="x"/>
</svg>
```

This is just a simple example with rectangular clipping masks, but should work with masks of any shape.